# How can I group mysql results based on a calculated colum?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to show the most commented posts of my web but is being impossible .-. I just got this mysql error all the time (Can't group on 'comments')

the relation between tables is:

table: post / colums: id_post, title, id_comment
table : comment / colums: id_comment, text, id_post

and this is the query I'm trying to use

```
SELECT p.title AS title, COUNT(c.id_comment) AS comments
FROM post p
INNER JOIN comment c ON p.id_post=c.id_post
GROUP BY comments DESC
```

Please any alternative or solution for this?

Comment: Your syntax is off -- `desc` is used with `order by`.  Perhaps you are just looking for `group by title`?

Comment: can you not ask questions with faulty characters in the titles thus forcing edits? Like you have on several occasions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to group by on the number of comments? You need `order by` clause to get the most commented to the top and group by posts:

```
SELECT p.title AS title, COUNT(c.id_comment) AS comments
FROM post p
INNER JOIN comment c ON p.id_post=c.id_post
GROUP BY p.id_post, p.title
ORDER BY comments DESC
```

You may want to have a `limit` clause as well to get the top N commented posts only.